# Problems using 'setValue'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to scripting and am attempting to write a script that will look for a value in one column ("Scheduled"), then if found will write the current date into another column, and ignore if a date has already been added.

The script works, but only assigns one value (date) a time.  When I run it a second time, it will assign the second value, etc.  I had it working earlier today but cannot for the life of me figure out what I changed.

Additionally, when I go back to the sheet, I can't remove the values the script has added.  When I clear the cells, the dates always come back on their own after a few seconds.  Sometimes copying and pasting a different value into the cells removes the script value, but not always.

Here's what I have - I am thinking I am overlooking something really obvious but can't seem to find it.

```
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[4];
var startRow = 2;
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
var data = dataRange.getValues();
//Logger.log(data)

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];

var schedulingStatus = row[3];
var timeStamp = row[2];
var scheduled = "Scheduled";

  if(timeStamp === '') { 
    if(schedulingStatus == scheduled ) {
      return sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(new Date());
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You've got a `return` statement inside your loop, so it will exit after setting one value.

Comment: @Mogsdad *facepalm* Wow, that will do it.  My other issue is still present though - when clearing the cells on the sheet after running the script, the values automatically return.  Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Mogsdad you had a return value.

The reason the value would return after removing it is because your script has a trigger onEdit. Meaning that when you edit the sheet by removing the value the script runs and copies the value again. You can add a drop down menu to run the function and change the name so it does not run on every edit of the spreadsheet.

If you haven't already you can read more on triggers here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: Oh, yes!  Thank you.  I forgot that I used that initially because I wanted it to run on each edit, but then I changed my end goal.  I want it to run each night so I will set up a trigger for that.  I kept checking my triggers thinking that had to be what was happening but forgot about onEdit (as I said, I'm a beginner). :)  Much appreciated!